# Magento2: Product Import Issue

Tags: magento2, product-import

Product add functionality is working but update functionality is not working.

[image]

Please help

Comment: can you elaborate about the issue

Comment: @masudshaikh add proper desicription about the isuues

Comment: Please check the screenshot @jafarpinjar

Comment: Please check the screenshot @Dvs

Comment: @MasudShaikh, is the import success?

Comment: Yes, Process success then reindexes also completed. @jafarpinjar

Comment: But I don't know why a field is not updating.  @jafarpinjar

Comment: @MasudShaikh, possible to share the csv file?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Please check the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XLTHyRYrhOL_1A2_KH6XKZ_wuktUuCHM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can try this file.

[Download here sample file](https://easyupload.io/mneemz)

**May help you!!**

Comment: I have tried but is not working.

Comment: Please let me know what is missing therefrom me.

Comment: I have updated the file, add the missing columns or try with that file, if worked then import again with sku and remaining columns

Comment: Got the issue. The issue in the additional_attributes column. Now is working fine

Comment: @MasudShaikh, Great!!.

Comment: Please mention the answer in your post so I can accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: custom_product_id column the same name in additional_attributes column so there is getting the issue. When I delete the additional_attributes column then the issue is resolved.